# how to make database access quicker in a java web app with jax-rs and mongo

Tags: java, web-services, mongodb, jakarta-ee

I have a jax-rs running on glassfish. I have some EJB stateless session beans as endpoints for the service and my database is mongoDB.

I have a singleton that returns the connection from mongo.  (Is this ok by the way?).

Which is faster in the business logic:

a) have a singleton as a UserService for example that adds and retrieves users from the database 
or
b) have the add/retrive functions in the EJBs because they are threaded?

when is a "service" bean like that needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean MongoClient as a connection that is OK, because MongoClient instance represents a pool of connections to the database and you need only one instance of this object.

In your second question what you want to have is DAO or Service and DAO layers. The most common approach how to do it in JavaEE environment is to use stateless session beans.

If you declare your DAO/Service as your own singleton than you lose all advantages of EJBs. If you want to use @Singleton annotation than you have only one instance instead of a pool of stateless session beans which is less efficient. So you should use @Stateless annotation.